# Python OpenCV: Mutithreading with opecv video streaming

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, opencv

I wanted to run one multithread along with opencv video stream. I want to activate GPIO if the object gets detected for 3 seconds while the video is streaming constantly. I have tried with multithreading (join method) but the video gets paused during the thread call, because it is having time.sleep(). Is there any way I can stream the video constantly and parallelly run the thread? Below is the code behaving the same way. If I remove the join than time.sleep is not at all have any effect.

```
import threading 
import time
import numpy as np
import cv2

def print_hello():
    print("Hello")
    time.sleep(3)
    print ("World")

t1 = threading.Thread(target=print_hello)  

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)

    t1.start()
    t1.join()

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: you should use `.join()` after loop because `.join()` waits for end of thread and it blocks other code. But in your example problem is that `while` loop may run very, very many times in one second so it will create very, very many threads, If you  need only one thread then start it before loop and use some loop inside function to run it again and again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.join()` waits for end of thread and it blocks code - so it makes no sends to run it inside loop but you should run it after loop or at the end of program

Other problem is `.start()` in loop because `.start()` can runs thread only once so using it many times in loop will generate error.

You can start thread before loop and run some loop inside thread to run it all time.

```
import threading 
import time
import numpy as np
import cv2

# --- functions ---

running = True

def print_hello():
    while running:
        print("Hello World")
        time.sleep(3)

# --- main ---

t1 = threading.Thread(target=print_hello)  
t1.start()

# --- loop ---

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# --- after loop ---

running = False # to stop loop in thread
t1.join()

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

If you have to start thread in loop then you would have to also create new thread inside loop.

In this example I use key `t` to start new thread - without this it would create new thread in every loop so it would create hundreds of threads in short time so it makes no sense.

```
import threading 
import time
import numpy as np
import cv2

# --- functions ---

def print_hello():
    print("Hello")
    time.sleep(3)
    print("World")

# --- main ---

all_threads = []

# --- loop ---

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if key == ord('q'):
        break
    if key == ord('t'):
        t = threading.Thread(target=print_hello)  
        t.start()
        all_threads.append(t)

# --- after loop ---

for t in all_threads:
    t.join()

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But even pressing `t` many times you can create many threads at the same time and they will work together. If you don't need it then you would have to control if threat is still working and create new one only when it doesn't work any more - use `is_alive()` - so it can make it more complex.

```
import threading 
import time
import numpy as np
import cv2

# --- functions ---

def print_hello():
    print("Hello")
    time.sleep(3)
    print("World")

# --- main ---

t = None

# --- loop ---

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if key == ord('q'):
        break

    if key == ord('t'):
        if t is None or not t.is_alive():
            t = threading.Thread(target=print_hello)  
            t.start()
        else:
            print('previous thread is still running')
            
# --- after loop ---

if t is not None:
    t.join()

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: thanks! @furas, the last solution is the one I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

This is almost never a good idea:

```
t1.start()
t1.join()
```

The problem is, it defeats the *only* purpose of threads, which is, to be able to two two different things at the same time.

This makes more sense because "...some_other_thing...()" can be happening while t1 is doing whatever t1 does.

```
t1.start()
do_some_other_thing_concurrently_with_t1()
t1.join()
```